# joomla in subdirecory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla

I can't setup joomla in my servers subdirectory. In server's main dir i have .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} joomlasite.domaniew.pl
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/joomlasite
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ one/$1 [L]

 RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and in joomlasite subdir i have .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried several diffrent combinations but still I got error:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '(' in /homez.221/myserver/www/joomlasite/includes/framework.php on line 42`

How can I make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an issue with htaccess, the error that you are getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '(' in /homez.221/myserver/www/joomlasite/includes/framework.php on line 42

Is related to your Joomla instalation. [This thread on the Joomla forum](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=695168) talks about this particular error, you can try some of the troubleshooting from that thread, specifically make sure you have the right version of PHP and have the right handlers.

Comment: I think you're right! This error message comes from joomla - so redirect works, problem is somwere else